# Search leads to 404 page in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a problem in Magento. 
The main website has 5 different storefronts, I edited default theme and developed one of those 5.
Now I have a problem when I try to search for anything on my homepage. Instead of search results page, I get a 404 page.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please also include sample URLs of valid and invalid pages.

Comment: Also, please attempt to run the indexer for URL rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have installed "Customers who bought this product also purchased" extension. If yes probably the culprit is this extension. Delete or comment the following lines in `app/code/local/Jain/Bought/etc/config.xml`  under line number 34.

```
<rewrite>
    <result>
        <to>bought/result</to>
    </result>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same thing with mRecommender extension - 
[Search leads to 404 page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356109/search-leads-to-404-page-in-magento)

If you are using this then also search will return 404 page not found.

Fix -
Comment out following lines from -

> \app\code\community\Mateusz\Recommender\etc\confix.xml - line no 36

```
<rewrite>  
<result>  
<to>recommender/result</to>  
</result>  
</rewrite>
```